# Unable to embed google fonts to HTML file using @import in CSS file

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

I am trying to learn web designing and currently I amd learnig HTML and CSS. I want to embed google's sans-serif font into my CSS file using @import and by placing it at the top of my CSS file in order to change my HTML page's fonts. but after saving and opening the Index.html file with various web browsers (Chrome, IE, opera etc.) I dont see any font change. But when I paste my HTML and CSS codes to http://codepen.io online editor the changes appear and I can see the font change.

I linked the CSS file to my Index.html file using this code:

```
<head>
  <link re="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/screen.css">        
</head>
```

and my CSS file only contains the code below:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,700,700i');

body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #555;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;}
```

here are my HTML and CSS files:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nPvXFAYIYWQOM4YtZ7-iEtkUPXX8LsxP/view?usp=sharing

Is anything wrong regarding the codes or is there any problem with my windows settings?
any help well be highly appreciated.

Comment: it should be `rel=stylesheet` you're missing the "l"

Comment: @jplara
Tanx man. your right. now the problem is solved :)